# Print php array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How do i print array values from this query ?
I need something like 6475,7377,6367. (comma separated).

This is what i get when i do a  `print_r($myarray)`:

```php
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [gift_product] => 6475
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [gift_product] => 7377
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [gift_product] => 6367
            )

    )
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You could have handled this on the MySQL side using `GROUP_CONCAT`, something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(gift_product) AS products
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id;
```

Your current output indicates that you are getting back `gift_product` values over several records, when in fact you wanted to retrieve a CSV string of products.

Comment: now i have 

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [GROUP_CONCAT(gift_product)] => 6475,7377,6367
        )

)`

how do i print only 6475,7377,6367?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `implode` function after you `map` your array using `array_map`:

```
echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
  return $entry['gift_product'];
}, $myarray))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to fetch column wise data with [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php),

```
echo implode(",", array_column($arr, "gift_product"));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/0vYje)

**Output**

```
6475,7377,6367
```